# Inline styling in react (Progressbar progress)

Tags: css, reactjs, progress-bar, styling

Im trying to style the element with the className "progress", I can't for the life of me figure it out even after trying numerous possibilities.

Any help or hints I can get will be greatly appreciated! Here is the code for component:

```html
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      arrIterator: 0,
      counter: 0,
      sets: props.ids.sets,
      exercises: props.program,
      ids: props.ids
    }

    // Helper variable to decide when a new round starts --> Reset counter
    this.newRoundOn = ((this.state.exercises.length /this.state.sets) -1);

    // Gets percentage for progressbar
    let barPercentage = ((this.state.arrIterator / this.state.exercises.length) * 100) +"%";

    this.style = {
      width: {barPercentage} 
    }
  }

  // Renders Progress Bar
  renderProgressBar() {
    return(
      <div className="card-panel" id="progresjon-panel">
      <div className="row">
          <h5 className="col s8">Progresjon</h5>
          <h5 className="col s4 right-align">{this.state.arrIterator +1} / {this.state.exercises.length}</h5>
      </div>
      <div className="progress" style={style}>
          <div className="determinate"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: `style` is not defined. Try changing it to `<div className="progress" style={this.style}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your state in order to make the progress bar change its value. Check if some property changed using the `componentDidUpdate` method and then set a new `barPercentage` value:

As a small advice, you should avoid [passing props to state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down).

```js
constructor () {
   this.state = {
     barPercentage: 0
   } 
}

componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
  // Helper variable to decide when a new round starts --> Reset counter
  this.newRoundOn = ((this.props.exercises.length /this.props.sets) -1);

  // Gets percentage for progressbar
  let barPercentage = (this.props.arrIterator / this.props.exercises.length) * 100;

  if (this.props.arrIterator > prevProps.arrIterator) {
    this.setState({ barPercentage })
  }
}

render () {
  return (
    // [...]
    <div className="progress" style={{ width: `${this.state.barPercentage}%` }}>
      <div className="determinate"></div>
    </div>
    // [...]
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```html
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      arrIterator: 0,
      counter: 0,
      sets: props.ids.sets,
      exercises: props.program,
      ids: props.ids
    }

    // Helper variable to decide when a new round starts --> Reset counter
    this.newRoundOn = ((this.state.exercises.length /this.state.sets) -1);

    // Gets percentage for progressbar
    let barPercentage = ((this.state.arrIterator / this.state.exercises.length) * 100) +"%";

    this.style = {
      width: {barPercentage} 
    }
  }

  // Renders Progress Bar
  renderProgressBar() {
    return(
      <div className="card-panel" id="progresjon-panel">
      <div className="row">
          <h5 className="col s8">Progresjon</h5>
          <h5 className="col s4 right-align">{this.state.arrIterator +1} / {this.state.exercises.length}</h5>
      </div>
      <div className="progress" style={style}>
          <div className="determinate"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
    );
  }
```